# Administratively force Microsoft account into local account?

Tags: cmd.exe, administrator, microsoft-account

It looks like there may not be a way, but is there a command line tool or some other tool to force a Microsoft enabled account into a local account so the password can be reset?

If not, is there a way to export the user's files in such a way that when you open up browsers and such stored passwords and everything will still be saved?

Comment: Maybe this....https://www.howtogeek.com/230543/how-to-revert-your-windows-10-account-to-a-local-one-after-the-windows-store-hijacks-it/

Comment: You have to log into the account, in order to convert it into a local account, being connected to a MS account is optional always has been. Worth pointing out if the device doesn't have an internet connection when you attempt to log into the account the cache password is used.  How Windows caches passwords is well known.

Answer (score 0):

No, these "Microsoft Accounts" involve communication with Microsoft over the Internet.  For a long time, Microsoft Windows has supported multiple types of sources of authentication, including local machines or remote professional servers (using Active Directory).  Microsoft account is likely just another type of source of authentication.

You can open up browsers and see passwords; likely nearly all the data is saved.  (Maybe not flies using filesystem encryption that is tied to a specific user account, if you used that feature.)  The typical experience is that all data will still be available once you log in as a local administrator.